# Trouble with event bubbling and JavaScript checkbox

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an HTML table with checkboxes in its leftmost column. I want to be able to select the checkbox by clicking anywhere on the `<tr>` element. I've gotten it to work, but I when I click the checkbox itself it doesn't change state. I've tested this in Firefox 54 (I don't care about other browsers).

I've made a JSFiddle demonstrating my problem https://jsfiddle.net/a92to0tu/

```js
let table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let tr = e.target.closest("tr");
  let checkbox = tr.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  
  // This doesn't work
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
  
  // This works but I don't like it
  // setTimeout(function() {
  //   checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
  // }, 100);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>Click works here too</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>Click works here too</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>I can click the text/table row, but clicking the checkbox no longer works</p>
```

Comment: Check if the clicked element is a checkbox - see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a92to0tu/1/)

Comment: Please do not post code elsewhere. Links rot, see [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: the fix is `if(e.target !== checkbox)
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked` in your fiddle. `e.preventDefault()` is unnecessary.

Comment: @RobG: I didn't know how to embed the snippet. I used your reply to do update the question.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Your solution isn't really portable. There can be other inputs in the table that are not checkboxes

Comment: make necessary adjustments, I can't do all the thinking for you :p

Comment: Just adding the information for people stumbling over this later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a condition to make sure the click isn't targeting the checkbox:

```
if(e.target !== checkbox) {
```

```js
let table = document.querySelector("table");
table.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let tr = e.target.closest("tr");
  let checkbox = tr.firstElementChild.firstElementChild;
  
  if (e.target !== checkbox) {
checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>Click works here too</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td>Click works here too</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>I can click the text/table row, but clicking the checkbox no longer works</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a label element, then you don't need any script at all.

```css
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
td { border: 1px solid #999999;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="foo" name="foo">
      <td><label for="foo">Works here too!</label>
      <td><label for="foo">Works here three!</label>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not what I want. My minimal example doesn't convey that, but I want any cell in the `<tr>` to toggle the checkbox.

Comment: Then put a label in all the cells. ;-)